# Button on Excel ribbon needs to be clicked twice

Tags: office-js

Am using Office 365 to create addins for my Excel application.
I created a button using the manifest. The button comes out preety good in the excel ribbon. However, it needs to be clicked twice to call any function. Just wondering if there is any configuration which can enable me to call any function with single click only.

My manifest snippet -

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="button.xyz">
              <Label resid="abc" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="residLabelDisplaySettings" />
                                        <Description resid="residToolTip" /> </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon_solve_16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon_solve_32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon_solve_80" /> </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>def</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
```

Comment: Could you include the JS for your function file in the question? Also, are you seeing any errors or warnings in the console when you click the button?

Comment: we have the same issue, but its very inconsistent.